# How to show character with value \0 in text box?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a test/simulator app for COM connection. The values I am sending through COM port is an array of chars (char[]). Some chars in this array have values that are not shown in regular string object such as 0 (\0 means end of String). I want to show this values in text box for debugging/logging purposes but I have no way to show these characters.

For example my char[] is:

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'#','\0' + '+'};
```

EDIT: My exact string that I want to show is:

```
String command = String.Format("#CMD{0:X}{1:X}*", chars[0], chars[1]);
```

This string in debugger is shown as below:

```
#CMD\0+*
```

Comment: You are getting bytes from the serial port so store the in byte[].  The programmer's way to look at byte values is to display them in hex.  Use BitConverter.ToString(byte[]).

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape the character as `\\0`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
 string[] strings = new string[] {@"# ",@"\0 ", @"+ "};
 LblTestLabel.Text = strings[0] + strings[1] + strings[2];
```

With a result of: # \0 +